# Flask: list files from folder in template

Tags: python, flask

I am playing around with a little project in Flask, and I am very new to python in general.

I want to display a list of files in a folder:

- appFolder

  - static
  - templates
  - assets

    - templates

      - file1.html
      - file2.html
      - etc

I would like to list out the files in the second templates folder. I would like to list these out in an html template. I would like to send a dict containing the file name and url to a for loop in the template.

I would like some information on reading the folder and creating the dict from the folder contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()+"/assets/templates"
list_of_files = {}

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    list_of_files[filename] = "http://yourpath.com/"+filename
```